# scrollHeight not updating with dynamicly changed font size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically updating the font size of a textarea based on an input using this code:

```
$('.font-size').change(function() {
                var input = $(this).val(); // grab the input value
                var newsize = parseInt(input);

                if (input.length > 0)
                {
                    // replace css value on live preview 
                    $('.sizeable').css('font-size', newsize + 'px'); 
                    if (this.clientHeight < this.scrollHeight) {
                        alert("Generic message does not fit in allocated space.\n Please reduce the text size or reword your message.");
                    }   
                } 
            });
```

But for some reason the this.scrollHeight is not updating(remains the same as when it started) when the font is re-sized.

Am I  doing somthing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like `this` in your case refer to `input` element, try to target your `textarea` instead:

```
$('.font-size').change(function () {
    var input = $(this).val(); // grab the input value
    var newsize = parseInt(input);

    if (input.length > 0) {
        // replace css value on live preview 
        $('.sizeable').css('font-size', newsize + 'px');
        if ($('textarea')[0].innerHeight() < $('textarea')[0].scrollHeight) {
            alert("Generic message does not fit in allocated space.\n Please reduce the text size or reword your message.");
        }
    }
});
```

Here I've used [innerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/innerheight/) instead of `clientHeight`